# How to trigger an Control.Resize event without actually resizing?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, resize, controls

I'm not subclassing the control. Trying to trigger the event via `Control.Size = Control.Size` fails, since it does not trigger then even unless the new size is actually different.

Comment: if you are not resizing the control then why do you want to do resize!?

Comment: If you want to *redraw* the control then do Control.Invalidate()

Comment: I've got an observer waiting for the Resize to occur. Changing the observer to waiting for a repaint would be inappropriate since it just resizes an internal control.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are subclassing `Control`, you can call `OnResize` directly, or expose it on the API:

```
 public void OnResize() {
     this.OnResize(EventArgs.Empty);
 }
```

However, you can't do this for arbitrary controls. You could change the `Size` to-and-fro? Alternatively, you could use reflection, but that is hacky:

```
 typeof (Control).GetMethod("OnResize",
     BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
     .Invoke(myControl, new object[] {EventArgs.Empty});
```

Comment: Reflection would be possible, but it's probably an overkill and also feels really ugly.

Answer (score 3):

I always do this by calling the Control's Resize event handler:

```
control_Resize(null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the size of the control using: Control.Size = new Size(x,y);

Changing the size of the control will issue a resize event for that control and the control should resize.

Alternatively if you just want to redraw the control then do:
Control.Invalidate();

Comment: This is incorrect. Setting a new Size does not issue a resize event for that control.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do this, and in what scenario? You can call OnResize, for example, when you're in the control itself (ie. in your derived control class). (Or via Reflection, when you are outside.)

Apart from that, you'll probably have to change the control's size, since that is what the Resize event is for :)