# Force FlowLayoutPanel to re-layout all controls after they have been added and layed out prior

Tags: c#, forms, user-interface, controls

I have a `FlowLayoutPanel` which I add controls to when my form is first instantiated. After this I show the form to the user. I would like to allow the user to check a checkbox that will change the `WrapContents` attribute of the `FlowLayoutPanel` and have it re-layout all of the Controls I added to it initially.

I have read many posts on `SuspendLayout`, `ResumeLayout`, and `PerformLayout` but they all seem to only pertain to when you are initially adding controls and not after controls have been added.

So I think the solution is to remove all of the controls from the panel, change the `WrapContents` attribute, then re-add all of the Controls when the user checks the checkbox? This just seems like too much work, is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SuspendLayout`/`ResumeLayout` are typically used when you are adding controls to `FlowLayoutPanel` and don't want layouting to occurs after **each** addition. It is *suspended* until you say *resume* (possibly even forcing it).

In your case, you already have collection of controls ready. Changing `WrapContents` will cause layouting (obviously), but only once. There will be no gain from using `SuspendLayout`/`ResumeLayout`.

If you have layout not updated immediately after changing `WrapContents`, then you forgot somewhere to call `ResumeLayout`, it should be called same number of times as suspending.

Comment: I have never called `Suspend/Resume` when changing the `WrapContents` attribute or at any other time in my code. I simply use `aControl.WrapContents = !aControl.WrapContents` to change it from one to the other. When that line is called the controls in the panel are not re-layed out. Nothing happens actually.

Comment: Perhaps my assumption is wrong, from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.wrapcontents.aspx): *Subsequent resizing of the panel will reapply the layout to the contained control*. Try to cause resize event. No idea [how](http://stackoverflow.com/q/515346/1997232).

Comment: I subclassed `FlowLayoutPanel` and added the overridden function `public void OnResize() {this.OnResize(EventArgs.Empty);}` which .. kind of worked. But it behaves very erratically. // So there really is not a method to just "relayout" the entire panel? I figure that would be a very useful method...

Comment: Actually [`ResumeLayout(bool performLayout)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k76wfs.aspx) overload can *force*, but only pending layout requests. You could try to add *fake* layout request (by adding something to `Controls` and then delete it, surrounded by suspend/resume). There is no need to directly force layouting after *nothing* (for me is a big surprise what changing `WrapContents` is not doing it, perhaps there were some difficulties to implement it). How is *behaves very erratically* looks like?

Comment: behaves erratic = my code isn't playing well with the panel, I'm new to forms and controls // I think I am going to try a different type of layout panel. I think there is something out there that can do better with my situation. Check out this post if you'd still like to help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23610824/is-there-a-better-way-to-handle-these-controls-flowlayoutpanel-seems-to-be-lack

Answer (score 3):

`flowLayoutPanel.FlowDirection = flowLayoutPanel.FlowDirection;` will force a re-rendering.

As for its elegance... let he who has not hacked cast the first stone.