# Is there a better way to handle these controls, FlowLayoutPanel seems to be lacking.

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, layout, user-controls

Currently I am using a `FlowLayoutPanel` to display my custom controls, it has worked well so far but now seems to be lacking when I want to change the layout of the controls per user requests. I have been trying to find a way to change the `WrapContents` attribute of the `FlowLayoutPanel` to re-apply the layout of the panel with the new attribute but keep falling short.

So I was wondering if there was a completely different solution.

I have two types of controls I want to display to the user, banners and indicators. For every banner there are 24-48 indicators along with it (They represent electrical boards). I want to display these controls to the user in two ways. First in one long list (which `FlowLayoutPanel` did pretty well with `WrapContents = false`) and second in columns of lists, one per banner (So each column would be headed by a banner with its indicators beneath.)

Below is a picture of how `FlowLayoutPanel` did at this task. For the first method of one long list it was simple, just set `WrapContents = false` and everything would line up in one nice long list. The problem I was having was for the second method; more specifically getting the `FlowLayoutPanel` to switch between the two methods of displaying the forms. As you can see with `WrapContents` set to `true` the `LayoutEngine` creates columns, but overflows them to the next column. (I never tried to fix this, I am still stuck on how to reapply the layout after setting `WrapContents` on a `FlowLayoutPanel`)

[image]

So my question is, is there a better solution to my problem.

- Is there a layout panel that I can display my controls in the two manners described?
- Also, easily switch between the two at the users request (by means of a checkbox/button that would redraw/relayout the controls)?

Comment: you should have another control basically combine `Banner` and all its `Indicators`, and then you can just put them in a `Panel` either vertically (as your method one) or horizontally (as your method two)

Comment: Would I be able to switch the layout in panel from vertical to horizontal during runtime?

Comment: This will be all down to your code, if you have code to show them `vertical` & `horizontal`, then of course you can switch the layout during runtime (by reapplying your code.)

Comment: So a `Panel` by default does not have methods to add/layout controls vertically and horizontally, I would basically have to write a `LayoutEngine` to do this? // I want to know if there is a layout panel that already can what I ask above by default?

Comment: Are all those `01` `Indicator 0` controls? This is scary and inefficient. You must redesign it to be a sort of list control. Have you seen `ListView` with groups? [Example](http://i.imgur.com/Zutoc.png). If these are `TextBox`'es, then perhaps you need something like `PropertyGrid`.

Comment: If you have the extra user control as I said, then you can just put them into your `FlowLayoutPanel` and set its `FlowDirection` to `TopDown` or `LeftToRight`

Comment: @Sinatr yes, they are all controls; textboxes. Can you explain why it is scary and inefficient? ( I can kind of see it, but I am not sure why exactly)

Comment: *Scary* because there are over 100 controls (much more) created. *Inefficient* because it's definitely a list, yet you are using controls. If I would have to do your job, then I'll take something scrollable and implement it. Notice: left picture is a normal `ListBox` (with owner drawn items and/or 2 columns) + caption, right one is something more complicated (many columns, many items). Perhaps taking `Panel` and simply draw everything yourself is the right way to go.

Comment: The controls though are "indicators". They have more behavior than plain `EditBox`es, they flash and change color etc. I know that can be done in a list by changing the background color of a list item, but in a list it is hard quickly glance and discern one list item from the next. // How much overhead does a `FlowLayoutPanel` have over a `Panel`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a layout panel that I can display my controls in the two manners described?

`FlowLayoutPanel` is the panel you are looking for, the problem you have is because your `banner` and `indicator` are not associated. so `FlowLayoutPanel` treat each of them as an individual control, hence the *overflow* you have observed.

As I pointed out in my comments, you need an extra user control to combine `Banner` and all its possible `Indicators`, and add this new control into the `FlowLayoutPanel` instead.

> Also, easily switch between the two at the users request (by means of a checkbox/button that would redraw/relayout the controls)?

When you done the first part, you can then switch layout by setting `FlowLayoutPanel`'s `FlowDirection` to `TopDown` or `LeftToRight` (with `WrapContents` set as `False`).

Comment: // side note: Weird, Changing the `FlowDirection` attribute re-lays-out the controls, while changing the `WrapContents` attribute does not (The reason I originally asked this question) // I think this will work for me, I think I will have a `FlowLayoutPanel` for each group of banners and indicators, and put them into the "main" `FlowLayoutPanel". // Though, does that seem inefficient?

Comment: yeah, that will work. And what I have suggested is for you to save some lines of code, by transferring that sub `FlowLayoutPanel` into a new `UserControl`.

Comment: if you have time, here is a related question I asked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616838/why-does-adding-a-panel-to-another-panels-controls-redraw-the-first-panels-cont I was having a hard time getting my controls to draw properly in the child `FlowLayoutPanels`. I am not sure why my fix makes them draw correctly, that is what the question is.